# Jones polynomial of cable knots

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, jones-polynomial

Let $K_{p,q}$ be a $(p,q)$-cable of the non-trivial knot $K$ in $S^3$.

Is there a closed formula for the Jones polynomial for $K_{p,q}$ as in the case of [Alexander polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123141/vassilliev-invariants-of-knots-and-their-cables) or [Seifert matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368955/seifert-matrices-of-cable-knots)?

Comment: This should be a linear combination of the colored Jones polynomials.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_polynomial#Colored_Jones_polynomial

Comment: As Ian points out, there must be an expression in colored Jones polynomial — this follows eg from the known description of the skein of the annulus.  In fact the formula has been written “explicitly”: https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ian Agol mentioned, if there were a closed formula for the Jones polynomial $V(K_{p,q})$ in terms of $V(K)$, this would give a closed formula for the colored Jones polynomials $V_n(K)$ in terms of the original Jones polynomial $V(K) = V_2(K)$.

However, this makes me think that there is no such simple formula. If there were, then we'd be able to easily give closed formulas for $V_n(K)$ for arbitrary $n$, but these are usually quite hard to generate. It's one reason why the Volume Conjecture is only known to hold in special cases: the first step of a proof for $K$ [1] is usually to give a closed formula for $V_n(K)$.

[1] Recently there have been proofs for other knots related to  "fundamental shadow links" in $\#^k S^2 \times S^1$, which proceed differently. This isn't terribly relevant to your question, but I'm mentioning it for completeness.